# is stack facilities is available is FORTRAN 77 because FORTRAN 77 doesn't support recursion?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

FORTRAN implementations do not permit recursion because

a. they use static allocation for variables

b. they use dynamic allocation for variables

c. stacks are not available on all machines

d. it is not possible to implement recursion on all machine.

have contradiction on it ans a is correct i understand but why ans c is wrong. is that time stack available for fortran but even fortran does't support recursion? can anyone explain me .

Comment: Stack is available but Fortran 77 doesn't use it. Where's the contradiction?

Comment: stack is available means fortran can use recursion so plz explain me why c option is wrong.

Comment: It *theoretically could*, but it *does not*.

Comment: There were not enough benefits for providing support for it in the Standard Language back then, considering language design, system architecture, technical complexity, backwards compatibility and demand from the market niche. Things changed years later, they finally added it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer: just too long for a comment.

Recursion was often seen as a *nice to have* - it was not required for most of the mainstream work.  Even nowadays, in huge systems written in C++, Java and C#, you hardly come across recursion.  I have seen some young grads going through great pains just to use recursion when it was totally unnecessary.

A stack may be available but it does not have to be used.  For instance, on the older compilers (IBM, DEC, Data General, Prime), the return address was stored before the routine or in a specific place - one word would be allocated for every routine.  So to return from a subroutine, all that was required was to jump/goto the address stored for the routine.  The variables were stored in a separate area so there really was no reason to use the stack since this technique is a lot faster and has no stack size limitation.

This implementation would work quite well on modern day microcontrollers like PIC, which only have 2 level stacks.

In the Fortran 66 days, some vendors implemented recursion by requiring the user to specify how deep the recursion would go.  For instance, the one I have used on Prime Fortran (circa 1975), I'm not 100% sure about the syntax but the code would look something like

```
      RECURSIVE (20) FACTOR
      SUBROUTINE FACTOR(N)
```

This would leave 20 words for the recursive calls.  Unfortunately, the variable values were *remembered* so you had to create your own version of a stack if you wanted dynamic variables.